# Auto format of XML file on save in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, indentation, code-formatting, xml-editor

Is there a way to automatically configure eclipse to do the formatting for XML file on save of XML files within eclipse?.

I understand that for Java Editor, I can see that there are options available to let the formatting happen automatically on save.

Please provide me some pointers on how to go about it.

Thanks,
Pavan.